# changing oracle users password for lifetime

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

I am having a user called "peter" in XE schema. I want to make this user password for life time it means the password should never expire.

Is that possible?

Regards,
Jerald

Comment: Isn't there a possibility to change expire to 'false' or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

You can alter the profile to set the password for lifetime. Try with the below steps, (Assuming that you have all the privileges)

```
SELECT profile FROM DBA_USERS WHERE username = 'peter'; --Default profile is 'DEFAULT'

ALTER PROFILE <profile_name> limit password_life_time UNLIMITED;
```

Comment: This should be the right way to do it. However, do NOT change the DEFAULT profile, as this is not a good practice. Instead, create a new profile based on the DEFAULT profile and then change that profile.

Answer (score 0):

1. Login as SYSTEM
2. Go to Home > Administration > Manage Database Users
3. Click on the user
4. Uncheck the "Expire Password" checkbox
5. Click on "Alter User" to save changes

[image]

Comment: G.Vicario : It seems this is for apex users. I need to make it for my XE schema. Using sysdba privileges we can achieve but I don't know the queries.

Comment: Sorry it didn't help. Since you mentioned XE schema I thought you were using Oracle XE.